# Laravel relationship between multiple models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationship, models

I have the folowing models User, Test, Attempts.

User has access to tests (many-to-many)

```
public function tests(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Test');
}
```

I have table `attempts` with folowing columns:

```
- user_id
- test_id
```

I need to obtain all user tests with related attempts.

How can I acquire that by using eager loading?

Thanks.

Comment: these attempts related with what users or tests ?

Comment: Attempts are related with Users.
return $this->hasMany('App\Attempt');

Answer (score 1):

Ensure firstly that the reverse side of the relationship is setup so your Tests Model will require a belongsToMany relationship with Users like so:

```
public function Users(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

You can specify the table name for the pivot table by passing an additonal argument to the belongsToMany like so :

```
public function Users(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'attempts');
}
```

To eager load columns from a pivot you can make use of the withPivot method